# Can I change os.tmpname() in lua?

Tags: file, lua, filenames, tmp

I want to change the name of my temporary file.
I know os.tmpname() returns a temporary name and I was wondering if there is a way I can change it to what I want.

Comment: You can write whatever temporary file function you want if you don't want to use `os.tmpname` itself but you can't change what `os.tmpname` does. You can overwrite the default `os.tmpname` function with your `os.tmpname` function though if you want.

Comment: Even though [*monkey patching*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch‎) (changing core functionality by overriding) **isn't recommended** practice.

Answer (score 3):

If you can patch Lua, then just edit the pattern `"/tmp/lua_XXXXXX"` in `lua_tmpnam` in [loslib.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/loslib.c.html). This will work on any POSIX systems because it relies on [`mkstemp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html). You'll still be restricted to templates that look like a filename with six trailing `'X'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use libraries, use [luaposix](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/docs/index.html) instead. `mkstemp` and `mkdtemp` take a pattern as their argument.